Custom right click menu in phoenix?
I am writing a live-view web app with the need for a custom right-click menu. Is there some kind of builtin way of doing this or will I have to resort to custom javascript?

First, it would be helpful if you could specify which version of LiveView you are working with, as well as provide a bit more context about what you are trying to achieve.
After reviewing the latest stable documentation for LiveView (v0.20.17), I couldn't find any built-in features to handle this type of task. It seems more suited to a JavaScript solution. Keep in mind that LiveView doesn't aim to completely replace JavaScript, especially when rich client interaction is required. In such cases, I recommend incorporating JavaScript. That said, a good solution can be crafted by combining both approaches. For example:

create the custom menu in JS
Sending the event to the server (via events or socket, it will depends)
handling the event in the server.


I've just made an example hook for the right-click event based on the Petal framework boilerplate, in the hope that it might help, visible in my github (nseaseb)?

const rightClickHook = {
// This function runs when the element has been added to the DOM and its server LiveView has finished mounting
mounted() {
this.el.addEventListener("contextmenu", (event) => {
event.preventDefault(); // Empêche le menu contextuel par défaut
        let payload = {
            x: event.clientX,
            y: event.clientY,
            element_id: this.el.id,
            additional_data: "any_other_data" // Vous pouvez ajouter d'autres informations ici
        };

        this.pushEvent("right-click", payload); // Envoie l'événement "right-click" au backend
    });
},

// This function runs when the element is about to be updated in the DOM. Note: any call here must be synchronous as the operation

cannot be deferred or cancelled.
beforeUpdate() { },
// This function runs when the element has been updated in the DOM by the server
updated() { },

// This function runs when the element has been removed from the page, either by a parent update, or by the parent being removed

entirely
destroyed() { },
// This function runs when the element's parent LiveView has disconnected from the server
disconnected() { },

// This function runs when the element's parent LiveView has reconnected to the server
reconnected() { }, };

export default rightClickHook;

In the heex :

  <.h3 id="id_1" label="right click me (id_1)" phx-hook="rightClickHook"/>
  <.h3 id="id_2" label="right click me (id_2)" phx-hook="rightClickHook"/>


And for the event :

@impl true   def handle_event("right-click", async_fun_result,
socket) do
IO.inspect(async_fun_result)
{:noreply, socket}   end

